# How to pass data from controller to models in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I passed parameter from view to controller via URL. Now I want to send it from controller to model so that I can use it to pick data from tables. Here is my code:

controller:

```
function view(){
    if(isset($_GET['r'])) {
        $rank = $_GET['r'];
    }

    $rank=$this->uri->segment($rank);
    $this->load->model('names_rank');
    $data=$this->names_rank->get_names($rank);
    print_r($rank); 
}
```

model:

```
function get_names($rank){  
    $this->db->select('u.*,v.*');
    $this->db->from('unit_member u, Vyeo v');
    $this->db->where('v.fno = u.fno');
    $this->db->where('u.present = ""');
    $this->db->where('v.rank', $rank);
    $this->db->where('v.date_of_end="0000-00-00"');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

this is the result:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Missing
>   argument 1 for Names_rank::get_names(), called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\unit\application\controllers\names.php on line 32 and
>   defined

Comment: `$rank` is going to be undefined if `$_GET['r']` is not set, so I would either return if it's not set or set to `$rank` to some default value

Comment: Just a note in CI3 versions files and class should have first letter upper case only names.php to Names.php

Comment: its more a consistency guideline than strictly enforced (at this stage anyway). I follow this strictly, same as naming my models Modelname_model.php too

Answer (score 1):

This will work to send to model but your code isn't understandable for me, you re-declare the variable after setting it in the IF? are you trying to print_r() the output from the model?

I think you are trying to achieve this maybe?

```
function view() {

if(isset($_GET['r'])) {

$rank = $_GET['r'];
}else{

$rank = $this->uri->segment($rank);
}

$this->load->model('names_rank');

$data = $this->names_rank->get_names($rank);
print_r($data); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a **Parameter** to your model. First you have to call your model within your controller if you not enable it on autoload.

Your Model:

```
<?php
class AwesomeModel extends CI_Model 
{
   publif function do_work($param, $anotherParam)
   {
     //code here
   }
}

Then your controller:

<?php
class AwesomeController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        /*
         * load in constructor so not need to recall every time you want use it
         * second parameter is model renaming (optional)
         */
        $this->load->model('AwesomeModel', 'awe');                                               
    }

    public function pass_data()
    {
        $this->awe->do_work($param1, $param2);
    }
?>
```

Thats all.

Comment: he already called the model in-line in the controller method view() just before he used it, which is acceptable... that isnt the issue

Comment: im noy put it as an issue :)

Comment: In CI3 version the files and classes should only have the first letter upper case as per the user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world and models http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model